# Import error No module named skimage

Tags: scikit-image

I am building code on python using skimage. But I am getting import errors while using skimage.segmentation.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "superpixel.py", line 5, in
>
> from skimage.segmentation import slic
>
> ImportError: No module named skimage.segmentation

Comment: You need to include code and exact error message you getting in order to get help.

Answer (score 174):

You can use `pip install scikit-image`.

Also see the [recommended procedure](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html).

Comment: Not the recommended approach: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

Comment: @RavindranathAkila it looks like the link you provide says to do pip install the way Joseph answered it?

Comment: @user Please accept this answer for the benefit of the community

Comment: installed it and it did not help me, still says that can't find module `skimage`

Comment: For me, using your command caused `import numpy` erros. I used `python3 -m pip install -U scikit-image` instead and it worked magically!

Answer (score 27):

As per the official installation page of skimage  ([skimage Installation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html)) : python-skimage package depends on matplotlib, scipy, pil, numpy and six.

So install them first using

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-numpy python-pil python-scipy
```

Apparently skimage is a part of Cython which in turn is a superset of python and hence you need to install Cython to be able to use skimage.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cython
```

Now install skimage package using

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

This solved the Import error for me.

Comment: I just needed the two commands `sudo apt-get install python-skimage` and `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: only `sudo apt-get install python-skimage` is required

Comment: @Gaurav Ubuntu version?

Comment: @AlexanderPacha Ubuntu version?

Comment: I guess it was 16.10 back than.

Comment: @Ravindranath Akila it was 14.04

Comment: How can I install skimage in  canopy windows ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to Activate your environment :  E.g, `.\Env Folder\Script\ac`

Then:

```
python -m pip install scikit-image
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but it seems the question already contains a lot of similar answers like this. Variations thereof seem to have not much to do with the module in question.

Answer (score 6):

For OSX: `pip install scikit-image`

and then run python to try following

```
from skimage.feature import corner_harris, corner_peaks
```

Answer (score 5):

**OSX python3**

Just run this code in your terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-image
```

If you faced any other issues please check this [link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) for more.

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To  convince me otherwise, please explain how it works and why it helps to solve the problem. Also, try https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: DON'T USE SUDO PIP INSTALL

Comment: I strongly advise against sudo pip install (never use sudo)

Comment: @ComputerScientist Why not?

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3, try the following:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} scikit-image
```

Answer (score 3):

For python 3.5 in case you have multiple python versions and want to install with python3.5:

```
pip3 install scikit-image --user
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried using:

```
pip install scikit-image
```

It shows successful installation but when I import `skimage` it still gives me `NoModuleFoundError`.

This command worked for me:

```
python -m pip install -U scikit-image
```

Answer (score 3):

pip installation did not work for me. I solved the problem by trying

```
conda install scikit-image
```

For further information about installing scikit-image, visit the site - https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

Answer (score 1):

On Debian based distributions:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-skimage
```

and, if you use it for python 2 scripts:

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that skimage library is not installed on your python environment. Therefore, it is suggested to run the following command in the command prompt or python terminal or a code cell in jupyter notebook:

pip install scikit-image

Ofcourse, you should be online that PyPI repository be available for you.

Comment: Note for "or a code cell in jupyter notebook", it would explicitly be `%pip install scikit-image` in modern Jupyter/IPython. Because auto-magics are usually on by default, without a symbol will work, too. You want to be sure though not to use the install commands in conjunction with an exclamation point (`!` symbol). Use of the exclamation point doesn't insure the installation occurs in the proper environment. In 2019 the magic versions of the install commands were added, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

**Hey this is pretty simple to solve this error.Just follow this steps:**

First uninstall any existing installation:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
```

or, on conda-based systems:

```
conda uninstall scikit-image
```

Now, clone scikit-image on your local computer, and install:

```
git clone https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image.git
cd scikit-image
pip install -e .
```

To update the installation:

```
git pull  # Grab latest source
pip install -e .  # Reinstall
```

For other os and manual process please check this [Link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html).