# Module Not Found Error for Skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have imported the scikit-image library using the following code:

```
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
```

And I used the library here in my program:

```
        s = ssim(imageA, imageB)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

I have installed scikit-image on my computer, so I am not sure why it is not recognizing this library.

Comment: what is the name of your module ?

Comment: skimage @DrutaRuslan

Comment: in this is your problem, simple rename it, the name of your module don't need to be equal to the name of some of the packages

Comment: what is the module name exactly? I am not sure if mine is skimage, I am just not sure what a module name is

Comment: what is the name of your file where is all your code ?

Comment: it is called "object"

Comment: run `python shell` with `python` and `python3` and try to `import skimage` in both

Comment: it still says no module named skimage

Comment: did you try to update it ? `pip install scikit-image --upgrade` maybe you have an old version

Comment: I just tried to update it and it says that it is already up to date

Comment: @SKunkel Uninstall what yo have and follow [THESE STEPS](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) or follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087558/import-error-no-module-named-skimage)

Answer (score 0):

skimage.measure library has been renamed now. Instead of

> from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim

use

`from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim`