# I have already installed my scikit-image on Python

Tags: python-3.x

However, whenever I run the following:

```
import os
import cv2
import h5py
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
```

it keeps returning error as below :
   No module named 'skimage.transform'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087558/import-error-no-module-named-skimage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error No module named skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087558/import-error-no-module-named-skimage)

Answer (score 0):

It just works fine with these versions of the modules

```
import os
import cv2                            #opencv-python==4.1.1.26
import h5py                           #h5py==2.10.0
import numpy as np                    #numpy==1.16.5
from skimage.transform import resize  #scikit-image==0.14.5
```

If you have any specific version requirement please mention.