# I cannot train tensorflow

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am trying to follow these instructions in order to train tensorflow:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=1t1&utm_creative=255798340456&utm_targetid=dsa-498578051924&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9061578&gclid=Cj0KCQiA5dPuBRCrARIsAJL7oeh8O1BawcnisHgACgu2gxP1BcofUPxNxsMf2D7cOjC-7QYeuU3ZBZEaAuDnEALw_wcB

I execute this code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]

    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory,d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f)
                for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "/home/"
train_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "BelgiumTSC_Training/Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "BelgiumTSC_Testing/Testing")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)

# print the 'images' dimensions
print(np.array(images).ndim)

# print the number of 'images''s elements
print(np.array(images).size)

# print the first instance of 'images'
images[0]
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)
  File "loading_data.py", line 16, in load_data
    images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
NameError: name 'skimage' is not defined
```

I followed this link without any success:
[Import error No module named skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087558/import-error-no-module-named-skimage)

Comment: It looks like you need to import `scikit-image` with `import skimage`. If scikit-image is not installed, you can install it with pip or conda (see https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: I did the `import skimage` now I get:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_data.py", line 25, in <module>
    images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)
  File "loading_data.py", line 17, in load_data
    images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
AttributeError: module 'skimage.data' has no attribute 'imread'`

Comment: It's `skimage.io.imread`, the tutorial might have typos.

Comment: Because I am very new, is tensorflow a DNN that I only train it with input pictures? Can I configure it? What can I change in tensorflow? For example can I configure the internal stages and the weights of its neurons?

Comment: `1
4575
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loading_data.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(labels.ndim)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'` What is this error?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
```

use

```
import cv2
images.append(cv2.imread(f))
```